# Angular 7 Routing not working with Browser Back button (Hash changes not loading component)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, angular-routing

I have a weird situation with angular routing. (7.2.9 - my current angualr version) 
My current URL is `localhost:8080/en/myApp/home.html?q=name`
I used Hash routing methodology in Angular Routing where I want to append to the above preexisting url `(localhost:8080/en/myApp/home.html?q=name#/list)`

app.module.ts has appRoutes as follow

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'list', component: ListComponent },
  { path: 'pdp', component: ProductComponent}
];
```

When I land into home page, I use this.router.navigate method to manually go to list Component.
 which has router-outlet and it has below code

```
ngOnInit(){
this.router.navigate(['/list'])
}
```

And within the list component, I have dynamically listed anchor tags

```
    <div class="innerclass--productImage">
       <a [routerLink]="product.productURL">
         <img src="{{product.imageURL}}">
       </a> 
    </div>
```

and when I click on one of them, my URL now changes to  `(localhost:8080/en/myApp/home.html?q=name#/pdp).`

Everything seems to be working fine and the product component is loaded after I click on the dynamically listed component.

The real problem is when I click on the browser back button or forward button and when the URL changes to -

```
localhost:8080/en/myApp/home.html?q=name#/list (loads the ListComponent), 
  or 
localhost:8080/en/myApp/home.html?q=name#/pdp (loads the ProductComponent) `
```

the list component is not showing (when using browser forward or backward) up or respective component is not getting rendered as per hash change

My app.module.ts uses HashLocationStrategy import and I just use the routes with useHash set to true.

Comment: Please clarify: Your route path is set as `pdp` but your routerLink points to `/productComponent`? I've actually never seen something like this ...

Comment: @devnull69 - sorry about that confusion, I have edited the question to correct url values.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this would resolve your issue but a little hint. Try to check what the Promise resolved from router.navigate returns.

Bisacally, I'm using 7.1.4 and I see some navigating problems as well. I have three routes `list`, `load`, and `show` in my app. Show is depending on resolver to be returned. You navigate by going from `list` to to `load` route which does `router.navigate` in its components and `show` component is waiting until resolver will be returned successfully. Clicking UI around is fine. Browser's back button is one the problems now. The second is that when changing browser URL manually, and trying to resolve a resolver for `show` route all xhr requests are cancelled. However, when you do full reload of `load` page it's all fine.
The conclusion is we can fix full reload and back in browse actions with responding on falsy message from `router.navigate`

```
this.router.navigate('show').then(ok => {
  if (!ok) {
    // happens when browser back button and url change without reload
    this.router.navigate('list');
  }
});
```

Comment: Really thank you, this was the only way to fix it for now :)